# python tkinter - want to call a function when scrollbar clicked in ScrolledText widget

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

[Edits noted:]
I want to hook into the ScrolledText widget so that when a user clicks anywhere in the scrollbar (or even scrolls it with the mouse wheel, hopefully) I can have it call a callback function where I can
[Add: "set a flag, and then return to let the ScrolledText widget do its thing."]
[Delete: " do something first (like turn off automatic scrolling) before the scrolling action takes place."]

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do something *like* turning off automatic scrolling, or is that *actually* what you want to do?

If you want to turn automatic scrolling on or off, just check the position of the text before inserting text. If it's at the end, add the text and autoscroll. If it's not at the end, add the text but don't scroll. This will work even if they scrolled by some other mechanism such as by using the page up / page down keys.

You can check a couple of different ways. I think the way I've always done it (not at my desktop right now to check, and it's been a few years...) is to call `dlineinfo` on the last character. If the last character is not visible, this command will return `None`. You can also use the `yview` command to see if the viewable range extends to the bottom. It returns two numbers that are a fraction between zero and one, for the first and last visible line.

While the user can't turn auto-scrolling on or off by clicking a button, this is arguably better because it will "just happen" when they scroll back to see something.

Comment: Sorry for my poorly worded question. I got it to work with help from abarnert. But now I see what you are saying and that should work in combination with his even better (i.e. for mouse wheel and keyboard.)

Comment: Very good - Your method works for all forms of scrolling and I don't have to hook anything.

Comment: Here's the code: "if self.rtext.dlineinfo('end-1chars') == None:". Thank you much.

Answer (score 2):

Not without reaching inside the ScrolledText to get at the Scrollbar and the Text and hook their bindings.

And, while you *can* do that, at that point, why even use `ScrolledText`? The whole point is that it's does the scroll bindings automagically without you having to understand them. If you don't want that, just use a `Scrollbar` and a `Text` directly. [Tkinter Scrollbar Patterns](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm) explains how to do this in detail, but really, if you don't want to do anything unusual, it's just connecting a message from each one to a method on the other.

For example:

```
from Tkinter import *

def yscroll(*args):
    print('yscroll: {}'.format(args))
    scrollbar.set(*args)

def yview(*args):
    print('view: {}'.format(args))
    textbox.yview(*args)

root = Tk()    
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)    
textbox = Text(root, yscrollcommand=yscroll)
for i in range(1000):
    textbox.insert(END, '{}\n'.format(i))
textbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=yview)
mainloop()
```

---

If you can't muddle out the details from the (sometimes confusing and incomplete) docs, play around with it. Basically, `yview` is called whenever the scrollbar is moved, and `yscroll` is called whenever the view is scrolled. The arguments to `yscroll` are obvious; those to `yview` less so, but the docs do explain them pretty well.

Note that, when you've set things up normally, dragging the scrollbar or swiping the trackpad or rolling the mousewheel over the scrollbar sends a `yview`, which makes our code call `textbox.yview`, which then sends a `yscroll`, and that does *not* cause a new `yview` (otherwise, there would be an infinite loop). So, you see both methods get called. On the other hand, swiping the trackpad or rolling the mousewheel over the text, or using the keyboard to move off the bottom, sends `yscroll`, which again does not cause a `yview`, so in this case you only see one of the two methods.

So, for example, if you change `yview` to not call `textbox.yview`, you can drag the scrollbar all you want, but the text view won't move. And if you change `yscroll` to not call `scrollbar.set`, you can swipe around the text all you want, but the scrollbar won't move.

If you want a horizontal scrollbar as well, everything is the same except with `x` in place of `y`. But `ScrolledText` doesn't do horizontal scrolling, so I assume you don't want it.

---

If you really do want to dig into `ScrolledText`, you can look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/tkinter/scrolledtext.py) for your version, which is pretty trivial if you understand the example above. In fact, it's basically just an OO wrapper around the example above.

In at least 2.7 and 3.3, the `ScrolledText` is itself the `Text`, and its `self.vbar` is the `Scrollbar`. It sets `yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set` in its superclass initialization, and sets `self.vbar['command'] = self.yview` after `vbar` is constructed. And that's it.

So, just remove the explicit `scrollbar` creation, and access it as `textbox.vbar`, and the same hooking code as above works the same way:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ScrolledText import *

def yscroll(*args):
    print('yscroll: {}'.format(args))
    textbox.vbar.set(*args)

def yview(*args):
    print('yview: {}'.format(args))
    textbox.yview(*args)

root = Tk()    
textbox = ScrolledText(root)
for i in range(1000):
    textbox.insert(END, '{}\n'.format(i))
textbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
textbox['yscrollcommand'] = yscroll
textbox.vbar.config(command=yview)
mainloop()
```

Just be aware that this (the fact that `textbox` is a normal `Text`, and `textbox.vbar` is its attached `Scrollbar`) isn't documented anywhere, so it could theoretically change one day.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. To clarify, I don't want to change the way the ScrolledText works, I only want to reset a flag in my program that automatically scrolls forward following some incoming data. Now I will study your code.

Comment: @Harvey: I don't understand how this clarification and your original question fit together. You wanted a callback when the user clicks in the scrollbar. But now you're asking for a way to automatically scrolls the view forward. To do that, just call `textbox.yview` with the appropriate args (e.g., `textbox.yview('scroll', '1', 'pages')` to scroll down 1 page).

Comment: Sorry. No everything the ScrolledText does is fine. All I want to know (programmatically) is that the user clicked on the scrollbar, so I can set a flag. (Forget all I said about automatic scrolling - that is something in my program that I turn on or off.)

Comment: OK, then just put a `yview` hook in like the one above; it gets called when and only when the user clicks on the scrollbar, or does something else that the OS treats similarly, like scrollwheel/trackpad-swipe events while the cursor is pointing at the scrollbar.

Comment: Ah, Good! Now it works when I click the scrollbar. Mouse wheel scrolling doesn't set the flag though. Can I hook that, similarly?

Comment: @Harvey: The mouse wheel is either going to trigger the scrollbar command, or the text's yscrollcommand; which one it triggers is platform-dependent, and sometimes even situation-dependent. (For example, on OS X, it triggers the scrollbar if your pointer is over the scrollbar, the text if it's over the text; on one particular linux/GNOME box, it always triggers the scrollbar; etc.)

Comment: abamert, thank you for all the info. Even though I took as my solution from Bryan Oakley, your answer has a lot of good info and I think I understand python classes a little better because of it.